# Multiple calls to a void method using list parameter as return value is better than a method that return a List?

Tags: java, methods, return-type

In short, my question is: If a method is called multiple times, is it better in terms of memory consumption to make it *void* and use a *List* as parameter to return its values? In case it really saves memory, isn't it a bad practice as the code is harder to read?

Let me provide an example to make it clearer. Suppose I have a class *Car* and each car must belong to a *brand*. I have a method that returns all the cars from a list of brands and this method uses a *foreach* and a method that retrieves all the cars from one brand. Like the following code:

```
private List<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        result.add(getCarsBySingleBrand(brand))
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Car> getCarsBySingleBrand(Brand brand) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    result.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)) // retrieveCarsByBrand omitted
    return result;
}
```

A colleague of mine defends that the method *getCarsBySingleBrand* should be rewritten to be *void* and use a *List* as parameter and this list would contain all the cars as you can see below:

```
private List<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        getCarsBySingleBrand(result, brand))
    }
    return result;
}

private void getCarsBySingleBrand(List<Car> cars, Brand brand) {
    cars.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)) // retrieveCarsByBrand omitted
}
```

He argues that this way it consumes less memory, because he does not create a List everytime the method *getCarsBySingleBrand* is called. I think this is a kind of unnecessary optimization and is a bad practice because the code is harder to understand.

Comment: It's harder to understand because of the name.  A method whose purpose is to add to an existing list should not be called `getSomething`.  Make the name more meaningful and I think it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @ajb, my point is that it is harder to read not because the name (it is not the real name of my method, I used it just as an example) but it seems awkward to have a method that returns a value but is void.

Comment: In the first example, in `getCarsByBrands` `result` is a `List<Car>`, which adds `getCarsBySingleBrand` to `result`. However, `getCarsBySingleBrand` returns a `List<Car>`. You're adding a `List<Car>` to a `List<Car>`. Does that even compile?

Comment: That's a matter of opinion.  It looks to me like it's a method whose purpose is to build up an object, not a method that returns a value.  Kind of like the `add` methods of `List` or `StringBuilder`.  Giving it a name like `get###` makes it **look** like it returns a value, which is why I think the name is the biggest problem.  However, it could be that I don't have enough information--i.e. maybe an example of some code that uses these methods?  Out of context, I think it's hard to judge.

Comment: Slightly confused.  Your first snippet has `getCarsBySingleBrand` always returning a singleton list.  That being the case, couldn't `getCarsByBrands` just return the result from `retrieveCarByBrand` directly?

Comment: You should use `List`'s addAll method to add the cars retrieved for each brand, instead of add.

Comment: OK, on rereading the code, I think I may have been wrong about the code's purpose.  I guess the style that your colleague is proposing is so unusual for the purpose of retrieving something that I assumed it had to be something else and that the name was the problem.  Sorry...

Comment: General rule - a method should do ONE task.  Retrieving some data AND adding it to a list counts as TWO.  Do the adding outside of the method.

Comment: Do both! Pass the current list-in-progress in and return the final (amended) list back as a return value. This provides the advantages of both efficiency and chaining.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The second option *MIGHT* be more optimal.

The issue is the first way not only has to make another `List` object for every brand, which is then just thrown away but if there are a lot of cars for a brand, then Java will resize the list (which is initialized to the default size of 16) many times.  The resizing operation requires copying the array.  This could get expensive if you resize many times.

The second option only has one list and since resizing usually doubles the capacity, it should have to resize fewer times than the first option.

However, this is getting into micro-optimizations.  I wouldn't worry about this kind of thing unless you are noticing a performance issue and have done analysis to determine that this is a bottleneck.

If you are worried about the method name, I think having the word "get" in the name is throwing you off because it usually implies returning something. Naming it something like `addBrandOfCarsTo()` might make it read more like a sentence:

```
for(Brand brand : brands) {
    addBrandOfCarsTo(result, brand));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Both options are good, and depend mostly of your preferences:

- some preople prefer clarity (and each people have his own style).
- others prefer preformance, however small it.

If your case you could also call directly to `retrieveCarsByBrand` and uses its result:

```
private List<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        result.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand))
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or simplify `getCarsBySingleBrand` and uses its result:

```
private List<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        result.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand));
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Car> getCarsBySingleBrand(Brand brand) {
    return retrieveCarsByBrand(brand);
}
```

or do a compromise between clarity and performance changing the name of `getCarsBySingleBrand`:

```
private List<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        getCarsBySingleBrand(result, brand))
    }
    return result;
}

private void addBrandCars(List<Car> cars, Brand brand) {
    cars.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)) // retrieveCarsByBrand omitted


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use both worlds.
The only advantage in the second one is it consumes less memory. Making a functional method instead a void one will increase clarity, as said before, and will help in unit testing (you can mock the returned value).
Here is how I would do it:

```
private List<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    List<Car> result = new Arraylist<>;
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        getCarsBySingleBrand(result, brand))
    }
    return result;
}

private List<Car> addBrandCars(List<Car> cars, Brand brand) {
    cars.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)) // retrieveCarsByBrand omitted
    return cars;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

He is might be correct.

Let's explain *WHY*.

so in first example for each brand you are creating new list  in *`getCarsBySingleBrand`* method and than you have to add cars from newly created list in result list being in *`getCarsByBrands`*.

```
result.add(getCarsBySingleBrand(brand))
```

in this line you just get list from *`getCarsBySingleBrand`* and add all those elements to result.

But in second case you add cars **directly** to *`getCarsByBrands`* *list* , so you do less operations.

Also It's correct to say that first example consumes slightly more memory. But I think more problem here is just operations , not memory.

**Conclusion**:

In my opinion second method is not really a bad style. So you can make such optimizations if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

As @dkatzel said, the second option might be better. But that's only because in the first option, in method `getCarsBySingleBrand(Brand brand)`, you are unnecessarily copying `retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)` result to a fresh new `ArrayList`. This means that 3 different lists exist before the method `getCarsBySingleBrand(Brand brand)` returns:

- The one that holds the final result
- The sublist with the cars of one single brand, returned by `retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)`
- The new `ArrayList` you're using to copy the list returned by `retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)`

If, as suggested by @Narkha, in the first option, you simplified the method `getCarsBySingleBrand(brand)` by not copying the list of cars returned by `retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)` to a new `ArrayList`, or by just inlining `retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)` method, then **both options would be the same**, in terms of memory consumption. This is because in both approaches, the list of cars retrieved for a single brand would be copied to the list that holds the final result once per brand. This means that only 2 lists would exist at the same time:

- The one that holds the final result
- The sublist with the cars of one single brand, returned by `retrieveCarsByBrand(brand)`

As stated by others, this kind of optimization is hardly ever needed. However, you should know there's a more optimal way to do this, if you use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) (you should!).

```
private Iterable<Car> getCarsByBrands(List<Brand> brands) {
    Iterable<Iterable<Car>> carsGroupedByBrand = new Arraylist<>();
    for(Brand brand : brands) {
        carsGroupedByBrand.add(retrieveCarsByBrand(brand));
    }
    return Iterables.concat(carsGroupedByBrand);
}
```

This solution stores a list of sublists of cars, where each sublist holds the cars of each brand, and at the end **decorates** the list of sublists of cars into a single `Iterable` of cars. If you really, really need to return a `List` instead of an `Iterable`, then you could modify the last line as follows:

```
    return Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.concat(carsGroupedByBrand));
```

The key word here is *decorates*, meaning no actual copy of any sublist is performed. Instead, a special-purpose iterator is created, which traverses every element of the first sublist, and when it reaches its end, it automatically and transparently 'jumps' to the first element of the second sublist, until it reaches its end, and so on, until it reaches the last element of the last sublist. Please refer to Guava's [Iterables.concat(...) method documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#concat(java.lang.Iterable)) for further details.